# How to convert Hours to Numeric in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, time, date-arithmetic

I have a table in postgreSQL that have a hour column, i need to convert that column into a numeric one, like if i have 1h and 30 min i need it to be shown as 1.5

I tried to use convert and cast but it didn't worked.

There is a way to do this?

The actual data type of the column is TIME

The actual result show like this:

```
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 10"  "01:30:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 11"  "01:30:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 12"  "00:30:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 2"   "00:30:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 3"   "00:30:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 4"   "02:00:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 5"   "08:00:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 6"   "07:00:00"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 7"   "23:00:00"
```

and i need to show like this:

```
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 10"  "1.5"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 11"  "1.5"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 12"  "0.5"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 2"   "0.5"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 3"   "0.5"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 4"   "2.0"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 5"   "8.0"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 6"   "7.0"
501001  "DEMANDA"   2019    "Ciclo 7"   "23.0"
```

Comment: What is the actual datatype of your column? Also, please show us sample data and expected results as tabular text.

Comment: Sorry GMB, i edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
extract(epoch from mycol) / 60 / 60
```

This converts the `time` to a number of seconds, and then to the corresponding number of hours.